# Isolate a variable within a round function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like to isolate $C$ in the equation below. Is it possible ?
$A=Round(B*C*D/E)+1$

I tried this but the results are obviously not perfect:
$C=(E*(A-1))/(B*D)$

Comment: What is $Round(x)$?

Comment: @Tavish A function that  returns the value of a number rounded to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $$Round(BCD/E) =A-1 $$ it can be deduced that $BCD/E$ is no more than $(A-1)+0.5$ and no less than $(A-1)-0.5$, i.e. $$A-1.5 \le BCD/E \lt A-0.5 $$ Assuming $BD/E \gt 0$, $$\frac{E}{BD} (A-1.5) \le C \lt \frac{E}{BD} (A-0.5) $$ (if $BD/E \lt 0$ then the inequality just gets flipped). Any $C$ satisfying this inequality satisfies the original equation.

**Note:** Here, I’ve assumed that the $0.5$’s round *up*, e.g. $Round(17.5) =18$